# Is it possible to flash a device ROM to a AVD emulator or genymotion?

Tags: android, compatibility, genymotion, android-virtual-device

I'm working on some compatibility problem on Android development, My Android apps crashed on a rare device ROM, which has modified some framework(app.widget) code to cause the crash.

I want to reproduce the crash by my self without the device, I don't own the device and can't easily get the right device, except 2-hand market.

But the ROM I can download from the device's forum(system.img, userdata.img), Can I flash the ROM to the AVD or Genymotion directly? Any guide to achieve this?

Comment: "Can I flash the ROM to the AVD or Genymotion directly?" -- I doubt it. After all, the emulator is not hardware, and the ROM will have hardware drivers expecting to work with hardware.

Comment: Instead of trying to reproduce first, whats the exact error?

Comment: @JonasKöritz it is the ROM specify bug, because that the ROM's framework code(TextView stuff) is a little differ than the normal code. My custom TextView extends TextView, will make the selection logic crash in a specify serials of operation.    I already find the crash cause, and prevent it in the ROM using reflection, find the cause by dump the ROM's framework code. Map it to the exception stack.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no you can't. Device ROMs are entirely device specific. Genymotion runs on x86 (your Computer) which in most cases will not be the same architecture as your device. Even if you could "flash" this to genymotions "Flash-Storage", no executable including the kernel and bootloader will be able to start.